# two instances of tcpdump at the same time?

Tags: ip, packet-capture, tcpdump, network-interface

Are there any known problems in running two instances of `tcpdump` at the same time on the same network interface (with non-conflicting filters)?

I'm experiencing some weird timestamping and I thought that that could be the cause.

Comment: I'm seeing that when I start a second tcpflow, sometimes the first one stops capturing (but still runs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

packet filtering is usually done in the kernel so it shouldn't cause any missed packets or out of order packets in each tcpdump process.  If you're comparing the two different tcpdumps and seeing the slightly off time stamps I could see a couple of reasons for that but it's hard to say without knowing what specifically the issue is you're having.

Comment: Ok, the issue was somewhere else in my code and it had nothing to do with `tcpdump`. In any case, to avoid any problems, I simply merged the two filters and then rearranged the packets offline.